# Mark a POI as visited?

Tags: no-mans-sky

How can I mark a POI (Artifact, Buried technology module, Knowledge stones, Damaged machinery) as visited?

Or how can I filter them out from my HUD?

Comment: This would be especially helpful to prevent a useless (2nd or 3rd) fly to a POI I have already cleared. Or how do you manage not to travel multiple times to the same location?

Comment: I may be wrong, but in my experience, once I identify a POI (a manufacturing facility for example) the icon appears on my HUD, but once I visit that POI, it disappears from my HUD entirely and never reappears even with further scanning from the same location. Is that not the case for you?

Answer (score 1):

Once you reach the location, collect the item, exhaust the resource, or accomplish the objective at a POI, it will be removed automatically.

There are exceptions, for bases (yours and others) and for Portals.