# [Synthesis-Update]: How can I mark a visited place as "seen"/"checked", visibly noticeable?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I'm actually on a friendly planet with many POIs. Unfortunately, I can't remember all the places that I already have visited.

Do you know any possibility to mark such a visited place? I think about something like the "visited" tag on NPC's, but visible from a very far distance.

Or how do you manage to not re-visit already seen places?

Comment: I don't know about Synthesis update, but it was always a problem. Quests markers or scan markers (especially the ones made from space) are often will point to already visited places and even bug (the marker stay forever, visiting doesn't clear it). My rule of thumbs is: do not stay in the same system. I do 2 scans for upgrades per planet maximum and then move to a new system. My bases are always on unexplored planets and I never ever click scan button in space.

Comment: Previous question: [Mark a POI as visited?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/341666/30863)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an embedded solution to this. You can try manually logging location from Analysis Visor or taking a screenshot of visited place.

Comment: Sorry to ask @markol, but for how many hours do you play this game already? If you play it hundreds of hours, you will see that "manually logging location... or taking a screenshot of visited place" can't be a solution.

Comment: It is hard, but also possible, isn't it?